# Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

after updating VS for MacOS to the latest updates (version 8.8.5 (build 18)), I'm now facing the "framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement".
Can be reproduced in new Xamarin.Forms solution which will contain Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth, Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore or Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging Nuget packages in the iOS project.[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems to be an issue has been submitted :https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/414 .Do you have a try 
with the shared solution?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, and the problem was that the package was undownloaded. I fixed it by going to the project folder, then the Pods folder, GoogleAppMeasurement folder, Frameworks folder where you will see GooogleAppMeasurement.framework, right click on that and press "Download Now" and that should do the trick.